# T-SQL sum() of rand(checksum(newid()) is not random if appeared multiple times in the select list?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, random, aggregate-functions

Expression `rand(checksum(newid()))` is often used to generate random numbers.

While generating some test data, I executed following statement:

```
select rand(checksum(newid())) R1, rand(checksum(newid())) R2
from ftSequence(3)
```

where `ftSequence(N)` is a table function returning single column `N` and values `1, 2, 3 ... N` in its rows (as much as argument `N` is). Running this resulted to quite expected data:

```
R1                     R2
---------------------- ----------------------
0,817                  0,9515
0,3043                 0,3947
0,5336                 0,7963
```

Then it was necessary to find sum in each column, and I did:

```
select sum(rand(checksum(newid()))) S1, sum(rand(checksum(newid()))) S2
from ftSequence(3)
```

Surprisingly I got the same number in each column:

```
S1                     S2
---------------------- ----------------------
1,2276                 1,2276
```

Why it happens?
The same behavior for `avg`, `min` and `max` aggregate functions.
Is it query optimizer, or do I miss some logic?

---

More observations after comments.

Placing `sum(rand(checksum(newid())))` into CTE or subquery like

```
select
    (select sum(rand(checksum(newid()))) from ftSequence(3)) S1,
    (select sum(rand(checksum(newid()))) from ftSequence(3)) S2
```

or

```
select sum(R1) S1, sum(R2) S2
from (
    select rand(checksum(newid())) R1, rand(checksum(newid())) R2
    from ftSequence(3)
) R
```

as well as doing a trick like

```
select
    sum(rand(checksum(newid()))) S1
    , sum(rand(checksum(newid())) + 0) S2
from ftSequence(3)
```

worked, resulting to different values

```
S1                     S2                    
---------------------- ----------------------
0,7349                 1,478
```

Happy of that, and needed to produce more than one row of several different `avg(rand(checksum(newid()))) from ftSequence(3)`, I did following

```
select R.*
from ftSequence(3) S1
    cross join (
        select
            avg(rand(checksum(newid()))) R1,
            avg(rand(checksum(newid())) + 0) R2
        from ftSequence(3)
    ) R
```

and got following result:

```
R1                     R2
---------------------- ----------------------
0,6464                 0,4501
0,6464                 0,4501
0,6464                 0,4501
```

At this point I was not able to answer myself, whether is it correct result, or should values be all random? What are the ways to make all values random?

Comment: Interesting, here's another test that does not rely on your sequence function:  --expected result, different sums
SELECT SUM(R1) 'R1 Sum', SUM(R2) 'R2 Sum' 
FROM (
 select 
  rand(checksum(newid())) R1,
  rand(checksum(newid())) R2, name
 from sys.objects
) v

--suprise result, same sums
select
    sum(rand(checksum(newid()))) S1,
    sum(rand(checksum(newid()))) S2
from sys.objects

Comment: Interesting Question: Easy Answer ["The optimizer does not guarantee timing or number of executions of scalar functions"](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/350485/bug-with-newid-and-table-expressions) and in this case it evaluates it once. Whether there is any reliable way of suppressing this and having it re-evaluated I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I stated in the question, I was need a set of random test data, but not `rand()` which is uniformly distributed, I was need a set of

```
select avg(rand(checksum(newid()))) from ftSequence(@n)
```

that converges to gaussian distribution.

I found, that instead of `cross join` I can use `cross apply` statement with additional meaningless check of the outer scope data:

```
declare @rCnt int, @n int
set @rCnt = 5000000
set @n = 5

select R.*
from ftSequence(@rCnt) S
    cross apply (
        select
            avg(rand(checksum(newid())) + 1e-101) R1,
            avg(rand(checksum(newid())) + 1e-102) R2,
            avg(rand(checksum(newid())) + 1e-103) R3
        from ftSequence(@n)
        where S.N is not NULL
    ) R
```

However, I'm not sure it can be considered as a reliable approach.

Following could be more reliable alternative:

```
declare @rCnt int, @n int
set @rCnt = 5000000
set @n = 5

create table #Rand (ValNo int, R1 float, R2 float, R3 float)
create clustered index #IX_Rand on #Rand (ValNo)

insert into #Rand
select
    S.N / @n,
    rand(checksum(newid())) R1,
    rand(checksum(newid())) R2,
    rand(checksum(newid())) R3
from ftSequence(@n * @rCnt) S

select AVG(R.R1), AVG(R.R2), AVG(R.R3)
from #Rand R
group by ValNo
```

Comment: I'm not sure that `rand(checksum(newid())` converges to a Gaussian distribution does it? You could use the [Box–Muller transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Muller_transform) `SELECT SQRT(-2 * LOG(ABS(CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) AS BIGINT) AS FLOAT) / 9223372036854775807))) * COS(2 * PI() * ABS(CAST(CAST(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(8) AS BIGINT) AS FLOAT) / 9223372036854775807))`

Comment: Afaik, `rand(checksum(newid()))` is uniform, but `avg()` of a sequence of them converges to Gaussian (according to Central Limit Theorem). Of course, the less values averaged, the worse approximation is, but it is acceptable in my case.